# ¿Cómo obtener los datos del último documento creado en una colección de Firestore?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy haciendo un creador de post tipo blog con Angular y necesito cargarles una imagen destacada para que el JSON de la entrada que se vaya a mi colección `(entradas-blog)` de Firestore incluya:

```
* Título de la nota
* Contenido de la nota
* Fecha
* Imagen destacada
```

No tengo problemas con el título, contenido o fecha; pero lo que no consigo es la url de la imagen destacada.

Para subir la imagen estoy utilizando Firestore y Storage de Firebase. Esto me genera una colección `(img-destacada-blog)` con el nombre del archivo y la url del Storage.

Dentro de mi editor tengo un botón para seleccionar y subir la imagen, esta imagen se sube al storage y se hace referencia en la colección `img-destacada-blog`, así que necesito que al subir la imagen pueda obtener sus datos. Para poder utilizar algo como:

```
titulo: titulo_de_la_nota,
contenido: contenido_de_la_nota,
fecha: fecha_ahora
img_destacada: ultima-imagen-de-mi-coleccion-de-firestore.url
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener esa imagen?

Con esto obtengo los registros de todas las imágenes de mi colección:

```
this.imagenCollection = afs.collection<Imagen>('img-destacada-blog');
this.imagenes = this.imagenCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
  return actions.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Imagen;
    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return { id, ...data };
  });
});
```